# how to create eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

i want to get name in the table cattegory, using model company

table company

```
id   -> primary key
name
```

table posting

```
id             -> primary key
id_posting_job -> foreign key
id_cattegory   -> foreign key
name
```

table cattegory

```
id    -> Primary Key
name
```

in my relation database

1. id table company relation to id_posting_job in table posting
2. id_cattegory table posting relation to id in table cattegory

what the eloquent for get data name in the cattegory, if access through model company ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) here. I think it's pretty straightforward.

In General, setting up basic relations is a breeze in eloquent.